# Order of processing different Redis Streams messages

Tags: redis, microservices, redis-streams

Given that I have a service P (Producer) and C (Consumer) my P service needs to:

- Create an object X
- Create an object Y (dependent on X)
- Create an object Z (dependent on Y)
- Notify C about X, Y, and Z (via Redis Streams)
- C needs to use data from Z, Y, and X to do some local data persistence
- Updated to Y and fairly common, but to X are rare

From C's perspective, is there a way to guarantee that it had all the info it needed for successful persistence?

I know that services like Kafka and Redis Streams are not generally built for this stuff, but how does one overcome this?

**Idea 1:**

- Send X, Y, and Z in that particular order to the same consumer group. But if we scale the number of workers to anything above 1, we run into the problem

**Idea 2:**

- Instead of sending X and Y separately to C, I can send a compound object Z, which has Y and X embedded. But seems really like overkill - doesn't it?

Is there any obvious way to handle object dependencies?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe IDEA 2 is a better solution cuz I think keep the whole message in one data structure is a good idea.

And probably you can try to use multiple keys.

For example:

#### On Service P

```
def now_timestamp = datetime.currentstamp # let`s say it is 1515151551

redis sadd not_processed_timestamp 1515151551
redis set X_1515151551 INFO_OF_X
redis set Y_1515151551 INFO_OF_Y
redis set Z_1515151551 INFO_OF_Z
```

#### On service C, create a new thread

```
def new_task_timestamp = redis spop not_processed_timestamp # let`s say it is 1515151551
redis blocking-get X_1515151551
redis blocking-get Y_1515151551
redis blocking-get Z_1515151551

# process the rest
```

Answer (score 2):

This is a good question covered in this note about [Redis Streams](https://redis.io/docs/manual/data-types/streams/#differences-with-kafka-tm-partitions).

> We could say that schematically the following is true:
>
> If you use 1 stream -> 1 consumer, you are processing messages in
> order.
>
> If you use N streams with N consumers, so that only a given consumer
> hits a subset of the N streams, you can scale the above model of 1
> stream -> 1 consumer.
>
> If you use 1 stream -> N consumers, you are load balancing to N
> consumers, however in that case, messages about the same logical item
> may be consumed out of order, because a given consumer may process
> message 3 faster than another consumer is processing message 4.
>
> So basically Kafka partitions are more similar to using N different
> Redis keys, while Redis consumer groups are a server-side load
> balancing system of messages from a given stream to N different
> consumers.

So if you want to process them in order and use more than one consumer you will need to deal with that yourself.